# How to receive events when a MAF application running on UWP shuts down?

Tags: uwp, lifecycle, oracle-maf

The answer that sprang to my mind immediately was to use implement stop() and deactivate() methods in LifeCycleListenerImpl class

```
public void stop() {
    // code
```

}

```
public void deactivate() {
    // Add code here...
    // need to implement shutdown sync tasks here.
}
```

However, when we provided implementations for these two methods in the  LifeCycleListenerImpl class and deployed our MAF app on Windows 10, we observed that:

-- when application shuts down, neither stop() nor deactivate() is called.
-- When application is minimized, deactivate() is called.

Is there anything we need to do apart from
implementing stop() and deactivate() methods in LifeCycleListenerImpl class?

I think it would be a basic/common requirement that when a user is about to shut down an app, the app presents a confirmation message to the user.

Note that version we are using is: MAF 2.3.2, running on windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 type of event - Suspend and Terminate.

- Suspending - you can't abort it, but you can have 5 sec timeslot
  to do the cleanup task.
- Terminating - you can't abort nor have
  timeslot.

If the user close - Alt+F4, Close button, etc - the app, first Suspend event has come, then terminated. You CAN'T ABORT it, but you have 5 sec timeslot to cleanup.

You can get more detail about this - Application Lifecycle management on UWP. (refer the section 'app close')

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle

Comment: Thanks for providing details about UWP app lifecycle. However, we are only programming with the Oracle Mobile application framework and won't be able to control the UWP lifecycle.

Comment: MAF (or any additional "Framework") can't override the basic behavior of UWP app lifecycle. If MAF does not handle it correctly, you may need to implement it.